# How to do a single logistic regression with multiple data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, regression, logistic-regression

The goal is to make a single ordered logistic regression using multiple data frames with the same structure.

In the example below I joined two data frames to be able to do a single ordered logistic regression. However, I would like a solution that automates the process, since there are 417 data frames.

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)

#dataframe 1
party <- factor(rep(c("Rep","Dem"), c(407, 428)), 
                levels=c("Rep","Dem"))  
rpi <- c(30, 46, 148, 84, 99) # cell counts
dpi <- c(80, 81, 171, 41, 55) # cell counts
ideology <- c("Very Liberal","Slightly Liberal","Moderate","Slightly Conservative","Very Conservative")
pol.ideology <- factor(c(rep(ideology, rpi), 
                         rep(ideology, dpi)), levels = ideology)
data1 <- data.frame(party,pol.ideology)

#dataframe 2
party <- factor(rep(c("Rep","Dem"), c(410, 430)), 
                levels=c("Rep","Dem"))  
rpi2 <- c(26, 50, 140, 95, 99) # cell counts
dpi2 <- c(75, 86, 141, 61, 67) # cell counts
ideology2 <- c("Very Liberal","Slightly Liberal","Moderate","Slightly Conservative","Very Conservative")
pol.ideology <- factor(c(rep(ideology2, rpi2), 
                         rep(ideology2, dpi2)), levels = ideology2)
data2 <- data.frame(party,pol.ideology)

nrow(data1)
nrow(data2)

## Joining dataframes "manually"
dat <- bind_rows(data1,data2)

table(dat)
nrow(dat)

# fit proportional odds model

pom <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data=dat)
summary(pom)
```

So I tried to loop in an attempt to do a single regression with data1 and date2. I was not successful, as the regression considers only  data2.

```
## LOOP
data = ls(pattern="data")
for(i in 1:length(ls(pattern="data"))){
  pom <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data=i)  
}
summary(pom)
```

Could someone point me to a solution? I recently started studying the loop theme on R. Sorry if the question is silly.

Comment: Welcome to SO!!! The Q seems a bit unclear. do you need one logistic regression for each dataframes (like data1, data2) or you need one logistic regression for a combined dataframe of all 417 dataframes? are the structure of all *df* same?

Comment: You need to use `get` to get the data, using `i` as the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be create a list of dataframes(*assuming all dfs have similar structure and all are individual dfs in your environment with names as **data1**, **data2**, **data3**...*)

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list <- map(paste0("data",1:3), ~eval(sym(.x)))
```

Once you have the list created. then you can easily do whatever you want.

***Create regression for individual dataframes***.

```
result_list <- map(df_list, ~polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data=.x))
```

***Or, if you want to create one regression of combined dataframes.***

1. Combine all dataframe together.

   `big_df <- df_list %>% bind_rows()`
2. run your regression for combined df. **big_df**

   `big_df_result <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data= big_df)`

Comment: That's it! I need a regression of the combined data frames.
Thank you, your contribution will be very valuable!

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in your loop is not the data. It's the index of the character vector you created outside the loop. But be careful assigning the name to `data` as you then create one more item in the for loop! Best to rename that. Your other problems are that you never save the results of each model, only the last one. So use a list to save them all and then lapply to extract them.

```
library(MASS)  # For ordered logistic regression (polr)

## LOOP
my_list = ls(pattern="data")
pom <- list()  # initialise your pom
for(i in 1:length(my_list)){  # or seq_along(my_list)
  pom[[i]] <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data=get(my_list[i]))  
}

lapply(pom, summary)
```

You could also do this without a loop using `lapply`.

Comment: Great solution! But, I noticed that in your solution an orderly logistic regression is estimated for each df. In my case, I need a logistic regression for all combined data frames. I notice that all dfs have the same structure.

Anyway, his contribution helped me to better understand the iteration. Thank you!

Comment: I see. Your question was open to many interpretations. Anyway, once you've mastered how to use for loops, stop using them and use R's *apply family of functions!